# How does the Emotet trojan activates its remote copies?

Tags: virus, trojan, emotet

The Emotet trojan is active again and I read a bit about [how it propagates](https://www.malwarebytes.com/emotet/). This includes phishing and having users launch all kind of files (exes, fiels with macros, ...) - a typical method.

It also scans the network for writable shares (where it can copy itself) and tries to brute force accounts.

**Since it does not seem to use vulnerabilities to activate the remote copy <sup>(*)</sup>, how does it activates itself in a massive way?**

---

<sub>(*) an [answer to a similar question](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/218650/6341) suggests this as a vector, but see *How does Emotet spread?* in the [first linked article](https://www.malwarebytes.com/emotet/)</sub>

Comment: There is nowhere stated it brute-force accounts in the whole examination https://www.fortinet.com/blog/threat-research/deep-dive-into-emotet-malware.html

Comment: @tungsten: the article you linked (very interesting BTW) describes how the malware is activated (manually) and how it gets its payload. It does not discuss the propagation part (just states that *"Emotet is a trojan that is **primarily** spread through spam emails.*" (emphasis mine)